# why would .is_a? and .class give conflicting results?

Tags: ruby

I have three objects that are all the same class. One was created via `Item.new` and the other two were pulled from the database (Mongoid). I'm passing one/any of these objects to another method and checking the type in that method via `is_a?`:

```
def initialize (item, attrs = nil, options = nil)
  super(attrs, options)
  raise 'invalid item object' unless item.is_a?(Item)
```

Well, this raise is getting hit. So I check the class, is_a and instance_of in rails console. I'm getting conflicting results. Why would they have the same `class` but only one of them be an `instance_of` that `class`?

```
>> i0.is_a? Item
=> false
>> i1.is_a? Item
=> false
>> i2.is_a? Item
=> true

>> i0.class
=> Item
>> i1.class
=> Item
>> i2.class
=> Item

>> i0.instance_of?(Item)
=> false
>> i1.instance_of?(Item)
=> false
>> i2.instance_of?(Item)
=> true
```

Is there a better way to do this type checking of my inputs? Why would three things that are the same class not all be instances of that class?

Comment: *Are* they the same class? For example, AR associations claim to be Array, but they're not.

Comment: Can you add output of `i0.class.object_id` and same for other objects? May be it has something to do with classes reloading and you got two different instances of the same class.

Comment: @DaveNewton ok, is there a better way to investigate a class and is_a type stuff?

Comment: @KL-7 good suggestion, I don't want to add the output because I renamed the objects when I posted them here so I'm not sure which is which. But they did give me back different object_id's. So it looks like I should compare the object_id instead of .class.

Comment: I think `is_a?` is the most normal way to check object class. I believe there's something wrong with model classes loading in Mongoid. I had the same issue in my specs: after loading from DB `object_id` of a class was different from the one that was currently loaded. Unfortunately, I didn't find any solution back then and just changed my specs somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Mongoid, but usually, in a DB access library, you don't get the actual object out of the database but rather a proxy object that acts as a stand-in for the object stored in the DB. Since Ruby lacks the features to implement a perfect transparent proxy, you will sometimes see odd results, especially when using reflection or around object identity.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired on the @KL-7 comment, it must be happening sort of that:

```
class Item; end
class PseudoItem; end

# PseudodItem think it's an Item:
class << PseudoItem
  def inspect
    'Item'
  end
end

i0 = Item.new
i1 = PseudoItem.new

i0.class         #=> Item (correct!)
i1.class         #=> Item (wrong, due to redefinition of inspect!)

i0.is_a? Item    #=> true
i1.is_a? Item    #=> false, as it is a PseudoItem
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya, same problem here...

Problem resolved (bypassed) with am ugly:

```
i0.class.to_s==Item.to_s
```